# Sas calculation program doesn't run

Tags: sas

I have the following data set:

```
Date    jobboardid       Sales
Jan05     3              256    
Jan05     6              70
Jan05     54             90    
Feb05     32             456
Feb05     11             89
Feb05     16             876
March05
April05
. 
.
.
Jan06     6              678
Jan06     54             87
Jan06     13             56 
Feb06     McDonald       67
Feb06     11             281
Feb06     16             876
March06
April06
.
.
.
Jan07    6               567
Jan07    54              76
Jan07    34              87
Feb07    10              678
Feb07    11              765
Feb07    16              67
March07   
April06
```

I am trying to calculate a 12 month growth rate for Sales column when jobboardid column has the same value 12 months apart. I have the following code:

```
data Want;
set Have;
by Date jobboardid;
format From Till monyy7.;
from = lag12(Date);
oldsales = lag12(sales);

if lag12 (jobboardid) EQ jobboardid 
and INTCK('month', from, Date) EQ 12 then do;
    till = Date;
    rate =  (sales - oldsales) / oldsales;
    output;
end;
run;
```

However I keep getting the following error message:
    Note: Missing values were created as a result of performing operation on missing values.

But when I checked my dataset, there aren't any missing values. What's the problem?

Note: My date column is in monyy7. format. jobboardid is numeric value and so does the Sales.

Comment: Why does your code use ``Date1`` when your data set ``Have`` shows that the column is named ``Date``

Comment: @nathanesau I just corrected some mistakes I had made

Comment: Are you sure it's numeric values? Your values for jobboardid and sales seems listed as missing character to me (blank, should be a dot ).

Comment: @Jonas no...the dots are there to indicate that similar data continues for other months of the year, not that the data is missing.

Comment: Ok. Is it missing values for march05 and march06 for jobboardid and sales? If it is then doesn't your if-statement resolves to true and the rate will be calculated on missing values?

Comment: Your variable FROM will be missing for the first 12 records, because of LAG12. Thus I think INTCK will generate this message.

Comment: @Quentin I thought about this too but does it matter when FROM is not used in any calculation? Shouldn't the problem arise in the calculation of RATE?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you're in front of SAS please see if: if intck('month', . ,today()) then put true; will generate that note.

Answer (score 1):

The NOTE is being thrown by the INTCK() function.  When you say `from=lag12(date)` the first 12 records will have a missing value for from.  And then `INTCK('month', from, Date)` will throw the NOTE.  Even though INTCK is not used in an assignment statement, it still throws the NOTE because one of its arguments has a missing value.  Below is an example.  The log reports that missing values were created 12 times, because I used lag12.

```
77   data have;
78     do Date=1 to 20;
79       output;
80     end;
81   run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.HAVE has 20 observations and 1 variables.

82   data want;
83     set have;
84     from=lag12(Date);
85     if intck('month',from,today())=. then put 'Missing: ' (_n_ Date)(=);
86     else put 'Not Missing: ' (_n_ Date)(=);
87   run;

Missing: _N_=1 Date=1
Missing: _N_=2 Date=2
Missing: _N_=3 Date=3
Missing: _N_=4 Date=4
Missing: _N_=5 Date=5
Missing: _N_=6 Date=6
Missing: _N_=7 Date=7
Missing: _N_=8 Date=8
Missing: _N_=9 Date=9
Missing: _N_=10 Date=10
Missing: _N_=11 Date=11
Missing: _N_=12 Date=12
Not Missing: _N_=13 Date=13
Not Missing: _N_=14 Date=14
Not Missing: _N_=15 Date=15
Not Missing: _N_=16 Date=16
Not Missing: _N_=17 Date=17
Not Missing: _N_=18 Date=18
Not Missing: _N_=19 Date=19
Not Missing: _N_=20 Date=20
NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.
      Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column).
      12 at 85:6
NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 20 observations and 2 variables.
```

One way to avoid the problem would be to add another do block something like (untested):

```
if lag12 (jobboardid) EQ jobboardid and _n_> 12 then do;
  if INTCK('month', from, Date) EQ 12 then do;
      till = Date;
      rate =  (sales - oldsales) / oldsales;
      output;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Quentin probably have a neat suggestion for this but meanwhile i think that adding: and _n_ >12 ; to your if-statement should work. This way the if-logic only starts after 12 observations.

Comment: Added to the answer. I think need to use another DO block.

Comment: @Quentin It didn't work. It runs the program, creates the 7 variables, but with 0 observations.

Comment: I haven't worked through other bits of your code. Looks like maybe should be by  jobboardid Date; rather than by Date jobboardid;

Comment: @Quentin  It's still giving me the "missing values were generated message", but it also produced 7 variables and 20 obs. Now that's because I tested my data with the dates beginning from May2005 to June2006. I will try it with all the data sets and see if it works or not.